# Java Array index out of bounds Exception when getting string input in java

Tags: java, string, exception

I got an Java `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when getting String input in Java. Please help me. This is my code: I edited my code to split using : it says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at solution2.Solution.main(Solution.java:27)

```
public class Solution {

 static String search;

 public static void main(String[] args){

   String[] fn,ln,tp;
  boolean[] isSet;
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);      
 int no=sc.nextInt();

 String[][] temp=new String[no][3];
 fn=new String[no];
  ln=new String[no];
   tp=new String[no];
   isSet=new boolean[no];
   boolean flag=false;

     for(int i=0;i<no;i++){
   temp[i]=sc.nextLine().split(":");
   fn[i]=temp[i][0];
   ln[i]=temp[i][1];
   tp[i]=temp[i][2];
   isSet[i]=true;

     }

       System.out.println(temp.length);

      search=sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Which one is line 27? What is the input for which you're getting the error?

Comment: temp[i]=sc.nextLine().split(":");
   fn[i]=temp[i][0];
   ln[i]=temp[i][1];
   tp[i]=temp[i][2];   line we get error

Answer (score 1):

The exception is occurring on this line:

```
ln[i] = temp[i][1];
```

so it appears

```
temp[i] = sc.nextLine().split(":");
```

is not receiving enough tokens in the `:`-delimited string to have create `String` array of size 3.

You will need to ensure `temp[i].length == 3` to ensure that you can assign these tokens.

An example of valid input (note: no newline) is:

```
1 test:foo:bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs when you are accessing non-existent indexes on the array created from `split(":")`.

In this piece of code, `temp[i]` is not ensured to have values at index 0, 1, *or* 2, because if the `nextLine()` is something such as "dog", there are no colon characters to split around.

```
temp[i]=sc.nextLine().split(":");
fn[i]=temp[i][0];
ln[i]=temp[i][1];
tp[i]=temp[i][2];
```

To fix the issue, you should verify that the array indeed has the index before trying to access it.

```
temp[i]=sc.nextLine().split(":");
if (temp[i].length >= 3) {
    fn[i]=temp[i][0];
    ln[i]=temp[i][1];
    tp[i]=temp[i][2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is, that sc.nextLine() return new line String (e.g. "\n") after you press [Enter]. Second time it's wait for you input. See[Java String Scanner input does not wait for info, moves directly to next statement. How to wait for info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877529/java-string-scanner-input-does-not-wait-for-info-moves-directly-to-next-stateme)

In your case try to invoke sc.nextLine() before you processing:

```
sc.nextLine()
temp[i]=sc.nextLine().split(":");
```

**EDIT:** you are right, you must insert it after nextInt(), because nextLine() consume complete line.

Answer (score 0):

I insert sc.nextLine(). below int no = sc.nextInt(); line.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

```
static String search;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] fn, ln, tp;
    boolean[] isSet;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int no = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // **********

    String[][] temp = new String[no][3];
    fn = new String[no];
    ln = new String[no];
    tp = new String[no];
    isSet = new boolean[no];
    boolean flag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        temp[i] = sc.nextLine().split(":");
        fn[i] = temp[i][0];
        ln[i] = temp[i][1];
        tp[i] = temp[i][2];
        isSet[i] = true;

    }

    System.out.println(temp.length);

    search = sc.nextLine();
}
```

}