# Java Scanner doesn't wait for user input

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I am using Java's Scanner to read user input. If I use nextLine only once, it works OK. With two nextLine first one doesnt wait for user to enter the string(second does).

Output:

> X: Y: (wait for input)

My code

```
System.out.print("X: ");
x = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.print("Y: ");
y = scanner.nextLine();
```

Any ideas why could this happen? Thanks

Comment: when i try this it works fine. y will be printed out only after user input and enter. how does your scanner look? i used Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's possible that you are calling a method like `nextInt()` before. Thus a program like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int pos = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.print("X: ");
String x = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.print("Y: ");
String y = scanner.nextLine();
```

demonstatres the behavior you're seeing.

The problem is that `nextInt()` does not consume the `'\n'`, so the next call to `nextLine()` consumes it and then it's waiting to read the input for `y`.

You need to consume the `'\n'` before calling `nextLine()`.

```
System.out.print("X: ");
scanner.nextLine(); //throw away the \n not consumed by nextInt()
x = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.print("Y: ");
y = scanner.nextLine();
```

(actually a better way would be to call directly `nextLine()` after `nextInt()`).

Comment: @AnubianNoob the only problem I see with this question, is that it was posted before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877529/java-string-scanner-input-does-not-wait-for-info-moves-directly-to-next-stateme?rq=1