# how can i read two inputs in loop java

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.scanner

i want to read inside a for loop two variables with scanner class then save them in a collection Map code is below :

```
public class Example{

public static void main(String args[]){

    Map<String,Integer> mapSub = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
      for (int i=0;i<nbSubnet;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter name of the subnet "+i+" : ");
        String nameSubnet = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the subnet "+i+" : ");
        int sizeSubnet = scanner.nextInt();

        mapSub.put(nameSubnet, sizeSubnet);
    }
  }
}
```

but i get this exeption after running the code :

```
Enter name of the subnet 0 : 
Enter the size of the subnet 0 : 
IT
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at view.Main.main(Main.java:60)
```

any help would be great thanks

Comment: AFAIK, `IT` is not an `int`

Comment: i give it the string "IT" as name , what i expect  from the code to do , ask the string first and then ask for the integer which the size

Comment: I think that this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: i want assign the nameSubnet first not the integer

Comment: Type "IT" *before* you press the enter key. You did not give any name in your output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your input to make sure that you get the type you expect.  `IT` is not an `int`, so of course `int sizeSubnet = scanner.nextInt();` is going to fail.

At the very least, a try/catch would be a good idea.

```
int sizeSubnet;
try{
    sizeSubnet = scanner.nextInt();
} catch () {
    sizeSubnet = 0;
}
```

If you expect that `IT` should be `nameSubnet`, then you'll need to [make sure the scanner waits for the input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450551/3504957) with an extra `scanner.nextLine();`.

Comment: guys i want assign the nameSubnet first by  String nameSubnet = scanner.nextLine(); that's why i gave it the string "IT"

Comment: @azdoudyoussef then you should swap the inputs' places.

Comment: @azdoudyoussef That's why I updated the answer-- read the link to understand why you need to add the extra line.  What's happening is that you aren't waiting on the user's input, so the first thing you type is not being read as the name, its being read as the size.

Comment: thanks you @senschen you've right Java scanner doesn't wait for my input, that's why SE throws that exception

Answer (score 0):

The reason of exception here is that `scanner.nextInt();` returns an `int`,and at runtime you are passing **IT** which is type of  `java.lang.String`.
and an variable of type `int` can not store a `String`

Comment: Is this Exception rising when you tack input for second time?

Comment: This problem often rises when you try to take String input from console.Because the String termination symbol '\n' remains in the buffer.So when the controller come for the second time,Compiler think the '\n' is the input given by user and it takes '\n' as input,and dont wait for user input.
Try to flush the buffer before taking 2nd input ,and you will not face this problem again.

Comment: thanks friend @MehrajMalik yes it does not wait for user input this is a great explanation