# Scanning an integer and a for loop to scan some strings

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to scan an integer and run a loop to scan strings until that integer. But this code skips the first string...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <String> A = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many strings to add:");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter %dth string:\n", i+1);
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            A.add(s);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(A.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Any solution?

Comment: This might help: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/669576).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <String> A = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many strings to add:");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter %dth string:\n", i+1);
            String s = sc.next();         //This will wait until you give argument
            A.add(s);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(A.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Go through the SO post - [Java Scanner doesn't wait for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450524/java-scanner-doesnt-wait-for-user-input)