# Errorin update variable

Tags: java, variables

i want update my variable and my code has a error that i dont khow where i have error

```
    String name = " "; 
    String family = " "; 
    int age = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    int choise;
    while (true){
        System.out.println("1:Name  2:Family  3:Age ---- 0:Exit");
        choise = input.nextInt();
        if (choise == 0) break;
        else if (choise == 1){
            System.out.println("Please enter the name : ");
            name = input.nextLine();
        }
        else if (choise == 2){
            System.out.println("Please enter the family : ");
            family = input.nextLine();
        }
        else if (choise == 3){
            System.out.println("Please enter the age : ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: "i dont khow where i have error" - we don't either since we don't know what your code is _supposed_ to do, i.e. what you expect, and what it is doing instead.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?  what is the expected behavior?

Comment: the error is :
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Code_4.main(Code_4.java:14)
@tomerpacific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to run your code in my local and I found 2 issues there:

1. When application try to wait for input in if-else part, it's not waiting instead of loop to next iteration.
   [image]

2. Relate to no 1 and based on the result, application should be waiting for entering name. After I enter my name, it thrown an error. Why? Clearly that the application is not waiting for name, instead of choice.

The issue is clearly describe here:
[Java Scanner doesn't wait for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450524/java-scanner-doesnt-wait-for-user-input)

> The problem is that nextInt() does not consume the '\n', so the next call to nextLine() consumes it and then it's waiting to read the input for y

My suggestion is change `nextInt()` to `nextLine()` then convert to int manually

```
choise = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: @jhamon ya, thanks for correcting. Update my answer to adding my suggestion to OP.

Answer (score -1):

i change code to this and it is working now. but shoud i write input.nexline() or input.nexint() after name = input.nexline() or ..?

```
 String name = " "; String family = " "; int age = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    int choise;
    while (true){
        System.out.println("1:Name  2:Family  3:Age ---- 0:Exit");
        choise = input.nextInt();
        if (choise == 0) break;
        else if (choise == 1){
            System.out.println("Please enter the name : ");
            name = input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
        }
        else if (choise == 2){
            System.out.println("Please enter the family : ");
            family = input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
        }
        else if (choise == 3){
            System.out.println("Please enter the age : ");
            age = input.nextInt();
            input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```