# Java Console Prompt for ENTER input before moving on

Tags: java

I am creating a simply story, which will occasionally prompt the user to hit ENTER. It works the first time I prompt for it, but then it will immediately execute the other prompts, maybe because the program runs so fast by the time you let the ENTER key up, it already ran the check for the prompts.

Any ideas? Code Below.

```
    System.out.println("...*You wake up*...");
    System.out.println("You are in class... you must have fallen asleep.");
    System.out.println("But where is everybody?\n");
    promptEnterKey();

    System.out.println("You look around and see writing on the chalkboard that says CBT 162");
    promptEnterKey();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void promptEnterKey(){
    System.out.println("Press \"ENTER\" to continue...");
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use the scanner class

Comment: take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877529/java-string-scanner-input-does-not-wait-for-info-moves-directly-to-next-stateme)... Please read other questions before reposing the same thing

Comment: In the future, you can also `System.out.print(System.in.read());` to see what's going on. [This Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) points out that a carriage return and newline are being read off the in.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason why `System.in.read` is not blocking the second time is that when the user presses ENTER the first time, two bytes will be stored corresponding to `\r` and `\n`.

Instead use a `Scanner` instance:

```
public void promptEnterKey(){
   System.out.println("Press \"ENTER\" to continue...");
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Don't use scanner because you are not actually using the input.  Look at my solution below...it is better cause you do not need the input.

Comment: The input doesn't have to be used. Garbage can be entered on the line in a worst-case scenario and it will not have effect on the program once the expected /r/n input is performed.

Comment: @brso05 - They're both valid solutions.

Comment: True but you are initializing a Scanner object when you don't need it it is not effficient its a waste.

Comment: @brso05 - we get it. You posted an alternative answer. Trying to oversell it will not get you positive attention.

Comment: It's not overselling as a programmer you should try to be as efficient as possible if you start bad habits they will probably continue and get worse

Comment: I feel like this addresses the issue. Program execution will **ONLY** continue when `Enter` is pressed, and not when I slam my forehead into the keyboard and fill the buffer with `ADSFOJASD`. The alternative is to keep peeking at the System.in stack until you get the newline.

Comment: You shouldn't use something because it works you should use it because its the best solution to your problem

Comment: @brso05 If the user enters ABC then presses Enter on the first prompt, will he or she be able to hit Enter on the second prompt? If no then your approach does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I am using the Scanner class already to obtain other input from the user. I didn't know about the .nextLine() as .next() doesn't work without entering some sort of data.

Comment: And I will be using the Scanner option because it's easier to implement for `Enter`-only input. In this manner, it is the best solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It just moves on without waiting for an `Enter`. What's happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

If we keep your approach of using `System.in`, the right thing to do is defining the bytes you will want to read, change your prompEnterKey to this:

```
   public static void promptEnterKey(){
        System.out.println("Press \"ENTER\" to continue...");
        try {
            int read = System.in.read(new byte[2]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It will work as you need.
But, as the others said, you can try different approaches like the `Scanner` class, that choice is up to you.

Comment: If we're going with the System.in, we shouldn't allow it to continue unless `/r/n` is read off the stack. Else pressing random keys will result in code continuing when it shouldn't, per spec.

Comment: Yeah, you got a point, for a safer situation, he needs to vadidate this possible entries.