# Java Waiting for Enter Key Solution not Working

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, wait, enter

So I've tried to implement a solution for waiting on user to press enter to continue found here: [Java Console Prompt for ENTER input before moving on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184409/java-console-prompt-for-enter-input-before-moving-on)

However, when I try to use either of the solutions proposed I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at printLine.promptEnterKey(printLine.java:153)
at printLine.main(printLine.java:144)
```

and

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:176)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:342)
at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at printLine.promptEnterKey(printLine.java:155)
at printLine.main(printLine.java:146)
```

I made a test program before to make sure this would work as expected and it worked fine for me:

```
// import scanner for user-input
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{

    public static void promptEnterKey(){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        promptEnterKey();

    }

}
```

Here's my code, I am working on a program that will read the current line, print it and then wait for the user to hit enter before proceeding:

```
// import System.out
import static java.lang.System.out;

// import scanner for user-input
import java.util.Scanner;

// import File class
import java.io.File;

// import FileNotFoundException
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

// delete if ioexception not used
import java.io.IOException;

/* this is the main public class */
public class printLine {
    
  /* this method is used to execute the application */
  public static void main(String[] args){

    // create scanner for user input
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // user input for file
    out.println("This program will print the text file line by line, waiting for the user to hit the enter key");
    out.println("Please specify the file to print line by line: ");
    String textFile = userInput.nextLine();
    userInput.close();

    // try to open file
    try{

      // load the file
      File text = new File(textFile);

      // for reading the file
      Scanner textReader = new Scanner(text);

      // while there is another token...
      while (textReader.hasNextLine()){

        String curLine = textReader.nextLine();
        out.println(curLine);

        promptEnterKey();

      }// end while

      // close reader
      textReader.close();

    }// end try

    // catch FileNotFoundException error
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){

      out.println("File not found.");
      e.printStackTrace();

    }// end catch

  }// end main

  /* This method is for waiting for the user to press the Enter key.
     this was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184409/java-console-prompt-for-enter-input-before-moving-on */
  public static void promptEnterKey(){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.nextLine();

  }

}// end class
```

Here's the sample text excerpt that I am trying to use it on:

> ```
> There was nothing so VERY remarkable in that; nor did Alice 
> think it so VERY much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to 
> itself, `Oh dear!  Oh dear!  I shall be late!'  (when she thought 
> it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have 
> wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); 
> but when the Rabbit actually TOOK A WATCH OUT OF ITS WAISTCOAT- 
> POCKET, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to 
> her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never 
> before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to 
> take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the 
> field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop 
> down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge. 
> In another moment down went Alice after it, never once 
> considering how in the world she was to get out again. 
> The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, 
> and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a 
> moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself 
> falling down a very deep well. 
> Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she 
> had plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to 
> wonder what was going to happen next.  First, she tried to look 
> down and make out what she was coming to, but it was too dark to 
> see anything; then she looked at the sides of the well, and 
> noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book-shelves; 
> here and there she saw maps and pictures hung upon pegs.  She 
> took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was 
> labelled `ORANGE MARMALADE', but to her great disappointment it 
> was empty:  she did not like to drop the jar for fear of killing 
> somebody, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as she 
> fell past it.
> ```

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.
Thanks!

JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are closing the `userInput (System.in)` immediately after reading the file name `userInput.close();`

move that line to the end of your code

Scanner.close will also close it's underlying readable if it implements Closable interface, in your case that is System.in input stream:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_close.htm

Comment: that did it, thanks! I'll make sure to keep the closing to the end of the method.

Comment: @JesseTherrien you also have to be careful with creating new objects when it might not be needed. Your `promptEnterKey()` method creates a new instance of `Scanner` when you probably be better off passing the same `Scanner` object you created initially. I am not saying that is wrong here. I am simply saying those decisions could have adverse effects sometimes (and perhaps most of the time).

Comment: Yeah I was wondering about memory leaking with the current way I am doing it. I was concerned that if I used `textReader` it would skip a line of the file. But now looking at the code, I should be able to the `userInput` scanner I have for this purpose.