# My breaks won't fire after if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, break

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmpTest {

    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

// there is a second class with my constructors and other stuff of that nature        

        Employee e1 = new Employee(); 
        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        Employee e3 = new Employee();
        String no = "no";
        String yes = "yes";
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Please enter in the employee name");
            e1.name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter in the salary of that employee");
            e1.salary = input.nextDouble();
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to add a second employee?");

                String userInput = input.next();
                if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the employee name");
                    e2.name = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the salary of that employee");
                    e2.salary = input.nextDouble();
                }
 //this is where my break wont terminate the loop
//the console output just asks for the second employee salary and name without waiting for a user input

                if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
                    System.out.println("Okay");
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("Would you like to add a third employee?");

                userInput = input.next();
                if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the employee name");
                    e3.name = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the salary of that employee");
                    e3.salary = input.nextDouble();
                } 
                if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
                    System.out.println("Okay");
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String Scanner input does not wait for info, moves directly to next statement. How to wait for info?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877529/java-string-scanner-input-does-not-wait-for-info-moves-directly-to-next-stateme)

Comment: Very common problem with scanners. Calls like `nextInt` and `nextDouble` don't remove the newline character that the Enter key inserts into the input, so the next time you ask for any type of string, there's already a newline character in the input buffer, so it eats it up and moves on.

Comment: Thank you for the help everybody!!

Answer (score 0):

After my first wrong answer here's the correct thing. As by the JLS:

> A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the innermost
>   enclosing switch, while, do, or for statement of the immediately enclosing
>   method

So in your case you are `break`ing the inner `while(true)`-loop.

If you want to `break` some "outer" block you have to use `break` with a label like this:

```
loop:
  while(true) {
     .....
     while(true) {
        ...
        break loop;
     }
  }
```

Comment: @khelwood Shame on me - I stand corrected and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your break statement is breaking inner while loop but no break statement for outer while loop.

Comment: that observation is correct. That does not fully solve the problem yet, though...

Comment: Can u post the updated code with break for outer while?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide 2 break statements, one for the inner `while` loop and another for the outer `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer with some explanations on the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmpTest {

    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Employee e1 = new Employee(); 
        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        Employee e3 = new Employee();
        String no = "no";
        String yes = "yes";

        //initialized userInput here so that we can use it on the outer loop
        String userInput="";   

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Please enter in the employee name");
            e1.name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter in the salary of that employee");
            e1.salary = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            //nextDouble() reads only the double and doesn't finish the line, so we need to add nextLine() method after nextDouble()

            while (true) {

                System.out.println("Would you like to add a second employee?");
                userInput = input.nextLine();

                if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the employee name");
                    e2.name = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the salary of that employee");
                    e2.salary = input.nextDouble();

                    //again
                    input.nextLine();
                }

                if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
                    System.out.println("Okay");
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("Would you like to add a third employee?");

                userInput = input.nextLine();
                if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the employee name");
                    e3.name = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter in the salary of that employee");
                    e3.salary = input.nextDouble();
                    input.nextLine();
                } 

                if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
                    System.out.println("Okay");
                    break;
                }

            }
            //do the remaining things 
            //add the condition for breaking the outer loop if there's any
            break;
        }
        //never forget to close the scanner
        input.close();
    }
}
```

> some notes:
>
> 1. **nextDouble()** reads **only 1 double** and **doesn't finish the line**, so I
>      added input.nextLine() to finish the line.
> 2. I just added a break on the outer loop, right after the inner loop.
>          I don't know if you have a condition for breaking the outer loop, or
>          if there's anything that you want to do after breaking the inner
>          loop
> 3. You can also convert that loop into method and just use "return"
>          statement to break out of the method. I don't know if it's allowed
>          though, so I just stick to how you created the program and modified
>          it a bit.
> 4. **Never forget to close the scanner** after using it

Comment: please mark this as answer if it helped you. Btw, I like @piet t 's answer but I never recommend using labels, It's like using goto, and such labels can cause spaghetti code